# Recommend good cropping software

Tags: software, cropping

I have a task to scan some documents onto computer..I will be taking use of my digital camera and then crop it.Please suggest me is there any software to auto crop the document and then save it so that the document is shown removing the background because I have use the same in android,so I guess it might be available for computers as well

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a software recommendation. Software tends to change quickly, and these questions rarely get good, comprehensive answers, instead attracting lists of single-point "this works for me" suggestions, and eventually spam from people pushing their own software.

Comment: I haven't voted to close yet, but I feel that this is incidentally photography. The camera, in this case, is really just a scanner substitute. Add in Matt's comments and I just don't know that I see the question having value for many.

Comment: Yes I tried it,indeed a good software

Comment: I don't think cropping white space off scanned images is photography related

Comment: ... even if a camera is used, as J Cavan points out.  Very narrow scope for using automatic cropping like this, which wouldn't apply to general photography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to mass crop images, and are using a windows machine, try JPEGCrops. JPEGCrops is a freeware program developed by Toke Eskildsen. It has the ability to crop folders of JPEG files without image loss.

The largest problem with this software is that it can **ONLY** crop JPEG files. JPEGCrops can be found [here](http://ekot.dk/programmer/JPEGCrops/future.html) at Toke's website.

If you are using a Macintosh, the OSX (or later) standard program Preview will work just fine for hastily cropping large amounts of photos.

### EDIT

As Bart Arondson, OSX Lion does not allow for Preview to crop multiple images, though previous versions, including snow leopard, allow for mass editing.

Comment: Cropping multiple images with Preview is not possible anymore as of Lion. In Snow Leopard it is still possible though.

Comment: mind that anything that writes JPEG will cause some loss, as JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm.

Comment: If you have a Mac, you don't need software, as the Mac can batch crop via Automator. See http://www.mactip.net/how-to-resize-batch-images-mac-automator/

Comment: indeed a good software

Comment: Lightroom 5 can batch crop and if you dont like the crop on one of the photos, you can select that photo and undo the crop. Lightroom also doesnt finalize the photo until you export the photo so the original is undamaged.